An Interesting Function $f(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{\ln x-\ln t}\mathrm dt$

Evaluate the function $f(x)$ where:
$$f(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{\ln x-\ln t}\mathrm dt$$
Hence, find $f((0.5)!)$.

I have an approach to solve this question as mentioned below, but I would like to know if there are any other, possibly better strategies. Can anyone kindly help me out? Any help would be highly appreciated.
My approach:
For a function $f(x)$ continuous in $(a,b)$:
$$\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm dx=(b-a)\int_0^1f\left((b-a)x+a\right)\mathrm dx$$
and
$$\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)\mathrm dx=bf(b)-af(a)$$
provided $f(x)$ is a bijective function $\forall x\in(a,b)$(for the second property).
Hence:
$$\int_0^x\sqrt{\ln x-\ln t}\mathrm dt=x\int_0^1\sqrt{-\ln t}\mathrm dt$$
Let: $$\mathcal I=\int_0^1\sqrt{-\ln t}\mathrm dt$$
Now, if $k\in R^+$: $$\int_{e^{-k^2}}^1\sqrt{-\ln t}\mathrm dt + \int_k^0e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt=-ke^{-k^2}$$
$$\implies\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{e^{-k^2}}^1\sqrt{-\ln t}\mathrm dt + \int_k^0e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt=-\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k}{e^{k^2}}$$
As an exponential grows faster than a polynomial, the RHS is $0$. Hence:
$$\mathcal I=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt$$
This is half of the Gaussian integral since $e^{-x^2}$ is an even function:
$$\mathcal I=\frac{\sqrt \pi}2$$
$$\therefore \boxed{f(x)=\frac{\sqrt \pi x}2}$$
$\because$ $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$,
$$\implies (0.5)!=\Gamma(1.5)=\frac12.\Gamma(0.5)=\frac{\sqrt \pi}2$$
$$\therefore \boxed{f((0.5)!)=\frac{\pi}4}$$

$$I=\int \sqrt{\log (x)-\log (t)}\,dt$$
$$\sqrt{\log (x)-\log (t)}=u \implies t=e^{-u^2} x  \implies dt=-2 e^{-u^2} u x\,du$$
$$I=-2x\int e^{-u^2}\, u^2\,du$$ One integration by parts gives the antiderivative. Just use the bounds.
